# Обработка POST запроса REST API wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, request

Проблема заключается в чём, мне надо с фронта отправить некоторый JSON и прочитать его. Проблемы в прочтении нету, но не могу найти нигде как зарегистрировать POST/PUT запрос в вордпресе.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route('fcs', 'send', [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'query_put_test',
]);
});
```

Функция, что вызывается

```
function query_put_test(){
     return 'test';
}
```

Я не поимаю что куда записовать, чтобы в колбеке получить данные, отправленные с фронта, зарание спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы не правильно передаете параметр `methods` при регистрации маршрута.

для получения данных отправленых методом пост вы можете использовать один из вариантов:

```
$request->get_param( 'some_param' ) // где "some_param" название парметра который вы передаете
$request->get_params(); // метод для получения всех параметров
$request->get_body(); // метод для получения тела запроса
```

при этом нужно не забыть что калбак функция принимает параметр реквест.

Все вместе может выглядеть вот так:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('fcs', 'send', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'query_put_test',
    ]);
});
function query_put_test( WP_REST_Request $request ){
    return print_r( $request->get_body(), true);
}
```

подробнее о создании маршрута можно прочитаь здесь [register_rest_route](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_rest_route)